# Phone wasn't used in 6 months. Is there a way to unlock it?

Tags: samsung, lock-screens, developer-options

Unlock pattern forgotten. Developer mode on off. It asks for pattern to shutdown. 
Laptop recognizes it but thats all. Drivers up to date. ADB doesnt recognize it as device.

Comment: Mind about factory reset? All data will be erased

Answer (score 0):

You can reset the device from the recovery mode. So, you will have to give up your saved data inside the phone to get rid of the pattern which you have forgotten.